# Laravel 5 route not working

Tags: php, laravel, routes

This is my route: `/api/v1/user`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/{version}'], function($version){

    if ($version == 'v1') {
        Route::get('user', function(){
            return 123 ;
        });

    } else if ($version == 'v2') {

        Route::get('user', function(){
            return 456 ;
        });

    }
});
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145
```

Why is the $version not working?

Comment: I just move `root/public/.htaccess to root/.htaccess` and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use another structure for that.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/{version}'], function($version) {
    Route::get('user', function($version){
        return $version;
    });
});
```

When you try to group a route you should use the variable in your inner routing. Here you can filter for a version.

http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-groups

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it the group route variables have to be passed to the Route::get functions, so you're calling a grouping with a variable in the prefix, each of your Routes in this group have access to this variable as a parameter of their function..

(Which makes sense when you consider the idea of a grouping)

So...

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/{version}'], function(){

        Route::get('user', function($version){
            if($version === 'V1'){
               return 123;
            }
            elseif($version === 'V2'){
               return 456;
            }
        });
    }
});
```